# invalid syntax error python 2.7

Tags: python, raspbian

I have this If statement in my code:

```
        if h >= 65 and h < 75
            lcd.set_cursor(0,1)
            lcd.message("Medium")
```

And I get this error:

```
if h >= 65 and h < 75
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Can you please help me, I don't know why this happens.

Comment: You're missing a `:` at the end of the `if` line.

Comment: @WanderNauta trivial though it is, you should make that an answer.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan I actually voted to close this question ('simple typographical error') but didn't want to leave OP hanging.

Comment: @WanderNauta yeah, that works too :-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not put : at the end of your if statement.

```
if h >= 65 and h < 75:
   lcd.set_cursor(0,1)
   lcd.message("Medium")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a colon on your first line, i.e.:

`if h >= 65 and h < 75:`